# Creating URLs in php

Tags: php

I have a basic understanding on PHP. My question is, i'm developing my first project and my sample directory structure is [localhost/plugins/feed/index.php]. In accessing index.php in /plugins/feed/index.php file, I need at the browser address bar the Url to be localhost/feed instead of localhost/plugins/feed/index.php
Please i need your help

Comment: Use .htaccess to remove index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under **`DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory**:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^ plugins/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

**Explanation:** Above rules is matching URL patter that starts with `plugins` and have somthing like `/plugins/feed/index.php` and puts `feed/index.php` in `$1`. It makes an external redirection to `/$1` i.e. `/feed/index.php`.

As server automatically loads `index.php` file so you don't need to worry about that. Which means, `localhost/feed` is equal to `localhost/feed/index.php`

These are the flags used:

```
L  - Last
NC - Ignore (No) Case comparison
R  - External redirection (with 302) -- can be changed to R=301
```

[For more information about .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/.htaccess/info)

Comment: Thank u very much

Comment: The alike issue is...I'm creating my first php web App but the issue is how to customize links. I need to access a page in sitename.com/themes/frontend/login.phtml. The issue is, whenever i want to access login.phtml, i have to type a full link ( themes/frontend/login.phtml ) and usually the url will be the same at the browser address bar. But my wish is to have a short link like url(sitename/login) and the web address to be sitename/login. I use php and i'm a beginner in dynamic web development. Please help me.

Comment: As you are a beginner so I would suggest to learn the basics of `.htaccess` so you can write or at least tweak code. And the above problem can be resolved by updating this line in above code: `RewriteRule ^ plugins/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]` to `RewriteRule ^login/?$ themes/frontend/login.phtml [QSA,NC,L]`